# React - Trying to remove child component, but there is some issue with the function I pass

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to remove a child component by sending a function and an id and then calling that function 
when a button in the child is clicked.

Note: The child is a class component, the parent a functional component

Here is the function defined in the parent:

```
 const removeTable = (tableId) => {
    const newArray = tables.filter((el) => (el.id !== tableId)
    );
    console.log(newArray);
    setTables(newArray)
}
```

This is removing elements, but not the one I want. Instead of removing the element with the id I pass it, it keeps that number, starting from 0.

So when I click on the item with a id of 3, it only keeps 0-2. In this example it should keep 0-2 and 4-6. (The array is supposed to be 7 elements long, but somehow it is shortened (before the filter))
[image]

**What I've tried and Discovered:**

I was completely lost, so I decided to create a mock function without using the child:

```
const removeTabletest = () => {
const key = 1; 
const testArr = [{id:1,op:"adsad"}, {id:2,op:"adsad"},{id:3,op:"adsad"} ];
const fml = testArr.filter( (el) => (el.id !== key));
console.log(fml)
}
```

This function works as I expect.

Finally I stumbled on the fact that when I console.log(tables) at the beginning of the function, I am not getting the same data as in React Dev Tools. The tables array is not the full array I expect.

[image]

### [image]

But when I create another button that is called by the parent (instead of the child), then tables is logged correctly:

[image]

Any idea what is going on? or how else I can achieve this?

Comment: did not understood, in the first image you click in the button to remove the elment with id=3, and that is what the result shows. In the log there is elements with id 0, 1, and 2. What is not working correctly?

Comment: Yes, but there are originally 7 elements. I want to keep 0-2 and 4-end. The array is somehow cut to 4 before the filter step

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a difficult approach to use with React. Generally what you want to do is just `filter` your array in the render method based on `props` or `state`. If you need a child element to modify what you filter by, like a button, you would pass a callback to the child. Here is an example:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { hiddenItems: [] };
    }

    hideItem = item => {
        // to hide a row of the table we add it to the list
        // of hidden items.
        this.setState({ hiddenItems: [...this.state.hiddenItems, item] });
    }

    render() {
        // Create the table element by filtering out hidden items
        const table = this.props.items
              .filter(item => !this.state.hiddenItems.includes(item))
              .map(item => {
                  return (
                      <div key={item.id}>{item.contents}</div>
                  );
              });
        return (
            <>
              {table}
              // the onClick function could also be passed to a
              // child React object
              <button onClick={() => this.hideItem(this.props.item[0])}>
                Hide item 0
              </button>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Where `this.props.items` would look something like:

```
[{ id: 0, contents: 'blah blah'},
 { id: 1, contents: (<span>blah</span>)}]
```

Of course you can also have a function unhiding an item but hopefully this shows the general approach.